# How to import functions of another jupyter notebook inside another jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have coded a python script with different functions and now I want to import those functions inside another file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with this command:

```
 %run your_file.ipynb
```